# VSCode переопределить цвета сообщений для сonsole.error в терминале

Tags: javascript, консоль, visual-studio-code

По умолчанию все сообщения console выводятся  одном цвете:

```
console.error('error, test');
console.warn('warn, test');
console.info('info, test');
console.log(' log, test');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их переопределить?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode переопределить не удалось, но вот как можно изменить цвет переопределив сами функции:

```
const error_origin = console.error;
  console.error = (...data)=>{
    return error_origin('\u001b[31m' ,...data, '\u001b[0m');
  }

  const warn_origin = console.warn;
  console.warn = (...data)=>{
    return warn_origin('\u001b[33m' ,...data, '\u001b[0m');
  }

  const info_origin = console.info;
  console.info = (...data)=>{
    return info_origin('\u001b[34m' ,...data, '\u001b[0m');
  }

  const log_origin = console.log;
  console.log = (...data)=>{
    return log_origin('\u001b[35m' ,...data, '\u001b[0m');
  }

  console.error('error, test');
  console.warn('warn, test');
  console.info('info, test');
  console.log(' log, test');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а ещё есть https://github.com/chalk/chalk и куча других пакетов

Comment: @nörbörnën,  спасибо! Но нужно было повлиять на весь проект, не заменяя при этом его код, глянул мельком и chalk вроде предлагает использовать свои лог средства, хотя тоже вариант.

Comment: тогда https://www.npmjs.com/package/manakin

Comment: вообще, модулей, которые меняют цвет вывода, тьма, можно любой каприз удовлетворить